# Caching or prefetching Django's inverse relationships

Tags: python, django, prefetch

Consider a shema with a Publishers table and a Books table so that

```
def Publisher(models.Model):
  city = models.CharField()
  ...

def Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField()
  publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
```

In my template I wish to display a list of certain publishers with all its books. In my view function I fetch the desired Publishers with something like

```
publishers=Publisher.objects.filter(city='NY')
```

Then in my view I iterate over publishers and publishers.book_set.all like

```
{% for p in publishers %}
....
   {% for b in p.book_set.all %}
```

This works as expected except that it obviously hits the db like a zillion times.

How can I optimise the code so that django only hits the db once or twice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Django 1.4+, use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
Publisher.objects.filter(city='NY').prefetch_related('book_set')
```

In Django <1.4, use [django-batch-select](https://github.com/lilspikey/django-batch-select).

Comment: @team-rf In case you are not Django>=1.4, then you have to do this manually. Quick Google search revealed http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/.

Comment: I'm running django 1.4.1 and mysql and django generates as many hits as without prefetch_related ...

Comment: Make sure you are not filtering the `book_set` *at all*. `prefetch_related` can only fetch the full related queryset (i.e. the same as would be returned by `publisher.book_set.all()`). If you filter `book_set`, Django discards the prefetch and runs the query on the DB. If you need to filter `book_set`, then look at django-batch-select, which has a little more flexibility, but is not as seamless as `prefetch_related`

Comment: Indeed my publisher table is huge, so the query must be filtered.

Comment: Also fetch only the required fields to make the query faster.

Comment: @team-rf: filtering the `Publisher` portion doesn't matter. It's only a problem if you filter the `book_set`.

Comment: I did manage to increase performance with prefetch_related, but at the end, adding views with the merged data avoided surplus db trips and boosted the performance to the expected level.